# Navigation drawer - logo in header

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I made a `Navigation Drawer`. I added `ImageView` in `header.xml` but it doesn't display on the screen.

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main_activity">
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

`header.xml`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        style="@style/Text"
        android:text="@string/slogan"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/iv_logo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_logo" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Use `android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"` instead of `tools:src="@drawable/ic_menu"`.

Comment: Stupid mistake, thanks!

Comment: No Issues. Don't forget to up vote comment to help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace:

```
tools:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
```

with

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
```